# Jackson XmlMapper map from child element

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I´m using the Jackson XmlMapper to map and xml into a POJO but I have the following problem:

My XML looks like this (not the original one, only an example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <pojo>
        <name>test</name>
    </pojo>
</result>
```

The problem is, I don´t want to parse the "result" object. I wan´t to parse the pojo as an own object. Can I do this with XmlMapper?

thank you!

Artur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it but you must write some boiler plate code.
You must create an instance of `XMLStreamReader` to be able to do customized reading of your xml input. The `next()` method allows to go to the next parsing event of the reader. It's rather a tricky method() related to the internal rules of the reader. So read the documentation to understands particularities :

From the Javadoc:
  **int javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader.next() throws XMLStreamException**

> Get next parsing event - a processor may return all contiguous
>   character data in a single chunk, or it may split it into several
>   chunks. If the property javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing is set to true
>   element content must be coalesced and only one CHARACTERS event must
>   be returned for contiguous element content or CDATA Sections. By
>   default entity references must be expanded and reported transparently
>   to the application. An exception will be thrown if an entity reference
>   cannot be expanded. If element content is empty (i.e. content is "")
>   then no CHARACTERS event will be reported.
>
> Given the following XML: content
>   textHello</greeting>]]>other content The
>   behavior of calling next() when being on foo will be: 1- the comment
>   (COMMENT) 2- then the characters section (CHARACTERS) 3- then the
>   CDATA section (another CHARACTERS) 4- then the next characters section
>   (another CHARACTERS) 5- then the END_ELEMENT
>
> NOTE: empty element (such as ) will be reported with two
>   separate events: START_ELEMENT, END_ELEMENT - This preserves parsing
>   equivalency of empty element to . This method will throw an
>   IllegalStateException if it is called after hasNext() returns false.
>
> Returns: the integer code corresponding to the current parse event

Let me illustrate the way to proceed with an unit test :

```
@Test   
 public void mapXmlToPojo() throws Exception {
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory2.newFactory();
    InputStream inputFile = MapXmlToPojo.class.getResourceAsStream("pojo.xml");
    XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(inputFile);
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlStreamReader.next();
    xmlStreamReader.next();
    Pojo pojo = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlStreamReader, Pojo.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("test", pojo.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more on this (In order yo make this generic), I had a scenario where I had to extract a specific element and map that to java object, in this case we can put a conditional check whenever that tag encountered get that out and map the same. 
I have added `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` to ignore fields which is not needed, in case our pojo has less fields to map than what we are getting from end source.
Below is the tested code -

```
while (xmlStreamReader.hasNext()) {
            xmlStreamReader.next();
            if (xmlStreamReader.nextTag() == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT) {
                QName name = xmlStreamReader.getName();
                if (("spcific_name").equalsIgnoreCase(name.getLocalPart())) {
                    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
                    result = objectMapper.readValue(xmlStreamReader, Pojo.class);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```